# mod_rewrite replace '_' with '-'

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, replace

I'm almost there with a mod_rewrite rule, but I've caved in :)

I need to rewrite

```
country/[countryname].php
```

to

```
country/[countryname]/
```

however, [countryname] may have an underscore like this: 'south_africa.php' and if it does I want to replace it with a hypen: 'south-africa/'

I also want to match if the country has numbers following it: 'france03.php' to 'france/'

Heres my rule, its almost there but its still adding a hyphen even if there is no second part after the underscore.

```
RewriteRule ^country/(.*)_(.*?)[0-9]*\.php$ country/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

so currently 'country/south_.php' becomes 'country/south-/'

Can someone please help me find the missing piece of the puzzle? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I'm a little confused - you **don't** want `south_.php` to be replaced to `south-.php`? What about `south_1.php`, `south_12.php`? Can you have digits elsewhere, as in `south_a1b34.php` ?

Comment: sorry I didn't explain it very well!  Seems like I got it sorted. I've been told there will never be any urls like that. Good enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^country/([^_]*)_([^_]*?)\d*\.php$ country/$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

This rule will match urls with a *single underscore* - you'll need a different rule for more underscores or none.

If you want to make sure `$2` contains only letter and isn't empty, change `([^_]*?)` it to `([a-zA-Z]+)`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could do it over several passes:

```
# If request is for something in "country/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^country/.+\.php$

# Replace underscore and digits with (single) hyphen
RewriteRule [_0-9]+ \-

# Remove extension (and possible trailing hyphen)
RewriteRule ^(.*)-?\.php$ $1

# Final rewrite
RewriteRule ^country/(.*)$ country/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Untested ... and not necessarily "pretty" :)