# 301 Redirecting Multiple Pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My rewrite rule almost works but there are still some problems. Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ /?s=$1&search=GA [L,R=301]
```

The **first** problem now is that the redirect links to:

```
mydomain.com/?s=tag/&search=GA
```

How can I get rid of the second slash?

Now the **second** problem... when a tag contains more than 1 word (for example the tag marketing tips) the redirect is:

```
mydomain.com/?s=marketing-tips/&search=GA
```

How do I convert that - symbol to a + symbol?

Comment: not an expert on this so not posting as an answer, just a suggestion - maybe you need to escape the & with a backslash or whatever escape character applies in a regex? as for your second issue I can't advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# getting rid of trailing slash:
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*?)/?$ /?s=$1&search=GA [L]

# change "-" with "+":
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+)-([^&]+)&(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?s=%1+%2&%3 [L,NE]

# if there's no more "-", redirect:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&-]+)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I go to a URL like `mydomain.com/tag/some-thing-else-lots-of-dashes/`, I get redirected to `mydomain.com/s=some+thing+else+lots+of+dashes&search=GA`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your regex is picking up the slash from the incoming URL in it's collection, try moving it out and making it optional, also I made your selector less greedy:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*?)/?$ /?s=$1&search=GA [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks! No it works for tags that contain 1 word. But right now I want to work for tags that contain 2 words or more. Any suggestions for how I can convert that - symbol into a + symbol?

Comment: @OscarHelm take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144121/mod-rewrite-replace-with ... also you can test your regex with http://regexplanet.com or http://regexr.com